# Не подгружаются css-стили и файлы js

Tags: javascript, php, css, mvc

При переходе по адресу localhost/product/2 должна открываться страница товара с номером 2 и подгружаться все необходимые css-стили и файлы скриптов, но загружается страница без скриптов и стилей.

Выводятся вот такие ошибки в косоле браузера:

Refused to execute script from 'localhost/product/template/js/jquery.scrollUp.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Refused to apply style from 'localhost/product/template/css/font-awesome.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Папка template лежит в папке проекта.

При переходе по адресу localhost/product/2 должен вызываться метод actionView($id) в ProductContoller, где $id =2 , который пока не обращается к модели, а просто вызывает View.

Ниже файл ProductContoller.php

```
class ProductController
{
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        require_once (ROOT.'/views/product/view.php');
        return true;
    }
}
```

Все стили вызываются вот так:

```
<link href="template/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="template/css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

скрипты вот так:

```
<script src="template/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="template/js/jquery.scrollUp.min.js"></script>
```

Не могу понять почему стили и скрипты не подгружаются

Я ещё заметил, что при указании полного адреса localhost/template... для js и css все работает, но это неудобно и хотелось узнать как сделать так, чтобы этот адрес не нужно было везде прописывать.
Тоже самое работает и при адресе ../template...

Comment: ваш сервер ругается на тип файла, попробуйте для js указать атрибут `type="text/javascript"`, для css `text/css`

Comment: Не помогло. Я ещё заметил, что при указании полного адреса localhost/template... для js и css все работает, но это неудобно и хотелось узнать как сделать так, чтобы этот адрес не нужно было везде прописывать.

Comment: Тоже самое работает и при адресе ../template...

Comment: Вы уверены, что хотите брать скрипты от текущего адреса? При адресе `http://site.com/test` в Вашем случае скрипт будет вызван из адреса `http://site.com/test/template/js/bootstrap.min.js`. Возможно, сервер ругается из-за этого. Поставьте в адресах в начале `/`, чтобы файлы забирались от корня адреса.

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало. Оказывается проблема была в одном слеше

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть элемент, который пытается загрузить некоторый внешний JavaScript.

Указанный вами URL-адрес указывает на файл JSON, а не на программу JavaScript.

Сервер правильно сообщает, что это JSON, поэтому браузер прерывает работу с этим сообщением об ошибке вместо попытки выполнить JSON как JavaScript (что приведет к ошибке).

Скорее всего, основная причина этого заключается в том, что вы пытаетесь сделать запрос Ajax, столкнулись с ошибкой перекрестного происхождения и попытались исправить ее, сообщив jQuery, что вы используете JSONP. Это работает только в том случае, если URL-адрес предоставляет JSONP (который является другим подмножеством JavaScript), чего нет в этом.

Answer (score -1):

На всякий случай продублирую комментарий, который мне помог:

Вы уверены, что хотите брать скрипты от текущего адреса? При адресе http://site.com/test в Вашем случае скрипт будет вызван из адреса http://site.com/test/template/js/bootstrap.min.js. Возможно, сервер ругается из-за этого. Поставьте в адресах в начале /, чтобы файлы забирались от корня адреса.  – Vladimir Gonchar